# Why do filter parameters on OGC WFS not work?

Tags: wfs, ogc, feature-filter

On the website https://www.bezreg-koeln.nrw.de/brk_internet/geobasis/webdienste/anleitung_wfs.pdf is shown how to use filters in OGC WFS. There is also an example request:

```
https://www.wfs.nrw.de/geobasis/wfs_nw_dvg?VERSION=2.0.0&SERVICE=WFS&REQUEST=GetFeature&TYPENAMES=nw_dvg1_gem&FILTER=<Filter><PropertyIsEqualTo><ValueReference>GN</ValueReference><Literal>Kerpen</Literal></PropertyIsEqualTo></Filter>
```

Well, I have got another WFS from the same domain and there the filter does not work.

WFS capabilities:

```
https://www.wfs.nrw.de/geobasis/wfs_nw_alkis_aaa-modell-basiert?REQUEST=GetCapabilities&SERVICE=WFS
```

WFS Request test with filter (adopted from the upper example but of course by using a layer and a filter attribute from the new WFS):

```
https://www.wfs.nrw.de/geobasis/wfs_nw_alkis_aaa-modell-basiert?VERSION=2.0.0&SERVICE=WFS&REQUEST=GetFeature&TYPENAMES=AX_Flurstueck&FILTER=<Filter><PropertyIsEqualTo><ValueReference>gemarkung</ValueReference><Literal>Dortmund</Literal></PropertyIsEqualTo></Filter>
```

When I try to load that WFS request I get the following response in my browser:

```
<ExceptionReport xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/ows/1.1" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="2.0.0" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/ows/1.1 http://www.wfs.nrw.de/aaa-suite/schema/ogc/ows/1.1.0/owsExceptionReport.xsd">
    <Exception exceptionCode="InvalidParameterValue" locator="FILTER">
        <ExceptionText>
            Request rejected due to errors. InternalExceptionCode: iiOperationParsingFailed. Reason:
            <![CDATA[ Element 'Filter' not in expected namespace (http://www.opengis.net/fes/2.0) ]]>
        </ExceptionText>
    </Exception>
</ExceptionReport>
```

Why does the filter options work on the one but not on the other WFS?

And how is it possible to add filter options instead?

In the description of the WFS it is said that it is especially built to serve filtered data.

Answer (score 1):

One of your problems is that `gemarkung` isn't a simple string but rather a `adv:AX_Gemarkung_SchluesselPropertyType` so your query is invalid:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>                                                                                                   
<schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:adv="http://www.adv-online.de/namespaces/adv/gid/6.0" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml/3.2" targetNamespace="http://www.adv-online.de/namespaces/adv/gid/6.0" elementFormDefault="qualified">
  <import namespace="http://www.opengis.net/gml/3.2" schemaLocation="http://www.wfs.nrw.de/aaa-suite/schema/NAS/6.0/schema/gml/3.2.1/gml.xsd"/>
  <element name="AX_Flurstueck" substitutionGroup="adv:TA_MultiSurfaceComponent" type="adv:AX_FlurstueckType"/>         
  <element abstract="true" name="TA_MultiSurfaceComponent" substitutionGroup="adv:AG_ObjektMitGemeinsamerGeometrie" type="adv:TA_MultiSurfaceComponentType"/>
  <complexType name="AX_FlurstueckType">                                                                                
    <complexContent>                                                                                                    
      <extension base="adv:TA_MultiSurfaceComponentType">                                                               
        <sequence>                                                                                                      
          <element maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" name="inversZu_verweistAuf" type="gml:ReferenceType"/>           
          <element name="gemarkung" type="adv:AX_Gemarkung_SchluesselPropertyType"/>                                    
          <element name="flurstuecksnummer" type="adv:AX_FlurstuecksnummerPropertyType"/>                               
          <element name="flurstueckskennzeichen" type="string"/>                                                        
          <element name="amtlicheFlaeche" type="gml:AreaType"/>                                                         
          <element minOccurs="0" name="flurnummer" type="integer"/>                                                     
          <element minOccurs="0" name="flurstuecksfolge" type="string"/>                                                
          <element minOccurs="0" name="abweichenderRechtszustand" type="boolean"/>                                      
          <element minOccurs="0" name="zweifelhafterFlurstuecksnachweis" type="boolean"/>                               
          <element minOccurs="0" name="rechtsbehelfsverfahren" type="boolean"/>                                         
          <element minOccurs="0" name="objektkoordinaten" type="gml:PointPropertyType"/>                                
          <element maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" name="sonstigeEigenschaften" type="adv:AX_SonstigeEigenschaften_FlurstueckPropertyType"/>
          <element minOccurs="0" name="zeitpunktDerEntstehung" type="date"/>                                            
          <element minOccurs="0" name="gemeindezugehoerigkeit" type="adv:AX_GemeindekennzeichenPropertyType"/>          
          <element maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" name="zustaendigeStelle" type="adv:AX_Dienststelle_SchluesselPropertyType"/>
          <element maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" name="inversZu_beziehtSichAuf" type="gml:ReferenceType"/>        
          <element name="istGebucht" type="gml:ReferenceType"/>                                                         
          <element maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" name="zeigtAuf" type="gml:ReferenceType"/>                       
          <element maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" name="weistAuf" type="gml:ReferenceType"/>                       
          <element maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" name="gehoertAnteiligZu" type="gml:ReferenceType"/>              
          <element maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" name="beziehtSichAufFlurstueck" type="gml:ReferenceType"/>       
        </sequence>                                                                                                     
      </extension>                                                                                                      
    </complexContent>                                                                                                   
  </complexType>
```

But I didn't get any where with other attempted filters such as `adv:flurnummer > 2` but that might be because I don't really know anything about the data set.

You might want to experiment in QGIS, and then use the QGIS Network logger to provide you with some working URLS.

Answer (score 1):

As per Ians answer `DescribeFeatureType` for `adv:AX_Flurstueck` shows us that `gemarkung` isn't a simple literal

```
https://www.wfs.nrw.de/geobasis/wfs_nw_alkis_aaa-modell-basiert?REQUEST=DescribeFeatureType&SERVICE=WFS&version=2.0.0&typename=adv:AX_Flurstueck
```

We can discover values and structure for property `gemarkung` with a `GetPropertyType` request

```
https://www.wfs.nrw.de/geobasis/wfs_nw_alkis_aaa-modell-basiert?REQUEST=GetPropertyValue&SERVICE=WFS&version=2.0.0&typenames=adv:AX_Flurstueck&valuereference=gemarkung&count=5
```

Gives:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<wfs:ValueCollection timeStamp="2022-06-01T16:29:21.697+02:00" numberReturned="5"
    numberMatched="unknown" xmlns="http://www.adv-online.de/namespaces/adv/gid/6.0"
    xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml/3.2" xmlns:wfs="http://www.opengis.net/wfs/2.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.adv-online.de/namespaces/adv/gid/6.0 http://www.wfs.nrw.de/aaa-suite/schema/NAS/6.0/schema/AAA-Fachschema.xsd http://www.opengis.net/wfs/2.0 http://www.wfs.nrw.de/aaa-suite/schema/ogc/wfs/2.0/wfs.xsd http://www.opengis.net/gml/3.2 http://www.wfs.nrw.de/aaa-suite/schema/NAS/6.0/schema/gml/3.2.1/gml.xsd http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gco http://www.wfs.nrw.de/aaa-suite/schema/NAS/6.0/schema/iso/19139/20070417/gco/gco.xsd http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gmd http://www.wfs.nrw.de/aaa-suite/schema/NAS/6.0/schema/iso/19139/20070417/gmd/gmd.xsd">
    <wfs:member>
        <AX_Gemarkung_Schluessel>
            <land>05</land>
            <gemarkungsnummer>4394</gemarkungsnummer>
        </AX_Gemarkung_Schluessel>
    </wfs:member>
    <wfs:member>
        <AX_Gemarkung_Schluessel>
            <land>05</land>
            <gemarkungsnummer>4394</gemarkungsnummer>
        </AX_Gemarkung_Schluessel>
    </wfs:member>
    <wfs:member>
        <AX_Gemarkung_Schluessel>
            <land>05</land>
            <gemarkungsnummer>4394</gemarkungsnummer>
        </AX_Gemarkung_Schluessel>
    </wfs:member>
    <wfs:member>
        <AX_Gemarkung_Schluessel>
            <land>05</land>
            <gemarkungsnummer>4338</gemarkungsnummer>
        </AX_Gemarkung_Schluessel>
    </wfs:member>
    <wfs:member>
        <AX_Gemarkung_Schluessel>
            <land>05</land>
            <gemarkungsnummer>4394</gemarkungsnummer>
        </AX_Gemarkung_Schluessel>
    </wfs:member>
</wfs:ValueCollection>
```

In theory we can access values in this structure by using XPath expressions in the `ValueReference`, such as `gemarkung/AX_Gemarkung_Schluessel/land` to get at the values for land.

I can get a `GetPropertyType` request to work like:

```
https://www.wfs.nrw.de/geobasis/wfs_nw_alkis_aaa-modell-basiert?REQUEST=GetPropertyValue&SERVICE=WFS&version=2.0.0&typenames=adv:AX_Flurstueck&valuereference=gemarkung/AX_Gemarkung_Schluessel/land&count=100&
```

but I can't get a GetFeature request with Filter to work, so the server may not support such queries